# Firebase setCustomUserClaims then

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I have the following codes in the backend of my web app made with node.js:

```
admin.auth().verifyIdToken(req.body.token).then((user) => {
    admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, {
      identity: "ns",
      approved: false,
      reviewed: false
    }).then(() => {
      console.log(user);
    })
  })
```

Although, I am logging the user token after the custom user claims have been set. The custom user claims `approved` and `reviewed` do not appear in my token. I think the claims are set correctly, but why they are not appearing in my terminal log?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The token that you verifed contains a copy of the claims *at the time the token was generated*.  If you update the claims, that doesn't change what was delivered inside the payload of the token.  If you want to see the updated claims inside a token, the client will have to refresh the token and provide a new one to the backend for another verification.